# Help me understand this piece of Lua code

Tags: lua

I started programming in Lua few days ago. I have become familiar with the syntax and I have managed to write a module for Prosody XMPP server. I ran in to a snippet of code in Prosody server configuration(which is in Lua).

```
VirtualHost "example.com"
  enabled = false;
  ssl = {
    key = "certs/example.com.key";
    certificate = "certs/example.com.crt";
  };
```

I am trying to figure out how the table in the 2nd line is linked to the first line.

Is it a parameter to the VirtualHost function? i.e. can the code be written as:

```
VirtualHost "example.com", {
  enabled = false;
  ssl = {
    key = "certs/example.com.key";
    certificate = "certs/example.com.crt";
  };
};
```

Is there some Lua concept I need to study further?

Comment: I think this stack-exchange [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review?referrer=aWNm_PdciyFqjFW8CUacGw2 "code review") might be of interest to you. If it is show your support and help get it into beta! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no direct connection between the first line and the rest. The first line is equivalent to `VirtualHost("example.com")` - you don't need parentheses if a function call is passed only a single string parameter.

Looking at Prosody's source code, what is happening here is that the code that loads the configuration file uses a combination of `setfenv` and `setmetatable` to trap writes into global variables (`ssl` and `enabled`). When you write `enabled = false`, it doesn't actually set the global variable `enabled`, but instead it calls a function defined by the Prosody code which sets the property on the currently defined virtual host.

This is all implemented in the `parsers.lua.load` function in core/configmanager.lua.

You can read about `setfenv` [here](http://www.lua.org/pil/14.3.html) and about `setmetatable` [here](http://www.lua.org/pil/13.html) (specifically this code uses the [__newindex metamethod](http://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.2.html)).